# Simplify : $( \sqrt 5 + \sqrt6 + \sqrt7)(− \sqrt5 + \sqrt6 + \sqrt7)(\sqrt5 − \sqrt6 + \sqrt7)(\sqrt5 + \sqrt6 − \sqrt7) $

Tags: arithmetic, recreational-mathematics, contest-math

The question is to simplify  $(  \sqrt 5 + \sqrt6 + \sqrt7)(−  \sqrt5 + \sqrt6 + \sqrt7)(\sqrt5 −  \sqrt6 + \sqrt7)(\sqrt5 + \sqrt6 − \sqrt7)$ *without using a calculator* .
  My friend has given me this challenge . I solved it by expanding $$(a+b+c)(-a+b+c)(a-b+c)(a+b-c) = -a^4+2a^2b^2+2a^2c^2-b^4+2b^2c^2-c^4$$ and then substituting $a,b,c=\sqrt 5 , \sqrt6 , \sqrt7$ respectively to get the answer $104$ .
But I suppose there is a more elegant and easy way to solve this problem .
Can anyone find it ?

Comment: Which contest's question  did your friend get it from?Is it from the  BdMO 2006 Nationals?

Comment: @rahul I don't know but it probably isn't from bdMO .

Comment: Hmm. . .But I am sure this was the 6th question in the Junior section of the Bdmo 2006 nationals.

Comment: @rahul really ? then it may be. Can you share the link  to it ?

Comment: You can find the question from BdMO's official website in the Questions section.

Comment: In your a,b,c expansion, note the expression is invariant if you change the sign of one variable, so there will be no odd powers in the expansion. Also, the expression is invariant under cyclic permutation of the three variables, so you only need the first two terms, and the rest follow automatically.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As $$(a+b+c)(-a+b+c)=\{(b+c)+a\}\{(b+c)-a\}=(b+c)^2-a^2,$$

$$(\sqrt5 +\sqrt6 +\sqrt7)(−\sqrt5+\sqrt6+\sqrt7)$$
$$=(\sqrt6+\sqrt7)^2-(\sqrt5)^2=6+7+2\sqrt7\cdot\sqrt6-5=8+2\sqrt{42}=2\sqrt{42}+8$$

Again as  $$(a-b+c)(a+b-c)=\{a+(b-c)\}\{a-(b-c)\}=a^2-(b-c)^2,$$
$$(\sqrt5 −  \sqrt6 + \sqrt7)(\sqrt5 + \sqrt6 − \sqrt7)=\{\sqrt5 −  (\sqrt6-\sqrt7)\}\{\sqrt5 + (\sqrt6-\sqrt7)\}$$
$$=(\sqrt5)^2-(\sqrt6 − \sqrt7)^2=5-(6+7-\sqrt7\cdot\sqrt6)=2\sqrt{42}-8$$

So, the product $$=(2\sqrt{42}-8)(2\sqrt{42}+8)=(2\sqrt{42})^2-8^2=4\cdot42-64=104$$

Answer (score 25):

Consider Heron's formula:  the area of a triangle with sides $a, b, \text{and } c$ is

$$
\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}
$$

where $s$ is the semi-perimeter $\frac12 (a + b + c)$.

Let $a, b, \text{and } c$ be $\sqrt{5}, \sqrt{6}, \text{and } \sqrt{7}$. Then the area is the square root of your expression divided by $4$.  So, what is the area of this triangle?  Use the law of cosines to find the cosine of the angle $C$ opposite $c$:

$$
\begin{align}
7 &= 5 + 6 - 2 \sqrt{5}\sqrt{6}\cos{C}\\
2\sqrt{30}\cos{C} &= 4\\
\cos{C} &= \frac{2}{\sqrt{30}}
\end{align}
$$

But the area of the triangle is $\frac12 ab\sin{C}$.

$$
\frac12 ab\sin{C} = \frac12 \sqrt{30} \frac{\sqrt{26}}{\sqrt{30}} = \frac12\sqrt{26}.
$$

Your expression is therefore the square of $2\sqrt{26}$, which is $104$.

Comment: Delightful! ${}$

Comment: The poster wanted a solution without needing a calculator or using complex algebra, and the expression looked like the one in Heron's formula.

Comment: _Wow_. I'm speechless.

Answer (score 20):

Use $$(a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2.$$

With $a=\sqrt6+\sqrt7$, $b=\sqrt5$ you see that the product of first two numbers is $(\sqrt6+\sqrt7)^2-5=8+2\sqrt{42}$. With $a=\sqrt5$, $b=\sqrt7-\sqrt6$ you get that
the product of last two is $5-(\sqrt7-\sqrt6)^2=-8+2\sqrt{42}$. One last application of this rule tells you that the answer is
$$
(2\sqrt{42})^2-8^2=168-64=104.
$$

Answer (score 18):

Here's a nice way to get the expansion the OP used:

The expression 
$$P(a,b,c)=(a+b+c)(-a+b+c)(a-b+c)(a+b-c)$$
is clearly a homogeneous polynomial of degree $4$, symmetric in its three variables.  It's also clear that the coefficient of $a^4$ (hence also $b^4$ and $c^4$) is $-1$.  Moreover, 
$$P(-a,b,c)=P(a,-b,c)=P(a,b,-c)=P(a,b,c)$$ which implies $P$ has no terms with any variable taken to an odd degree.  Therefore $P$ must be of the form

$$P(a,b,c)=r(a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2)-(a^4+b^4+c^4)$$

for some coefficient $r$.  It's easy to determine $r$ by letting $a=b=c=1$, for which we have

$$3=3\cdot1\cdot1\cdot1=P(1,1,1)=r(1+1+1)-(1+1+1)=3r-3$$

so $r=2$.  The rest of the answer follows what the OP did:

$$P(\sqrt5,\sqrt6,\sqrt7)=2(5\cdot6+6\cdot7+7\cdot5)-(5^2+6^2+7^2)=104$$

**Added 8/12/13**:  [Eric Jablow's invocation of Heron's formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/465103/simplify-sqrt-5-sqrt6-sqrt7-sqrt5-sqrt6-sqrt7-sqrt5-s/465446#465446) inspires one more approach:

Consider the triangle formed by the origin and two vectors $x$ and $y$, with $|x|=a$, $|y|=b$, and $|x-y|=c$.  There are two formulas for the area of the triangle:  Heron's formula

$$\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$$

where $s=(a+b+c)/2$, and the dot-product formula

$${1\over2}\sqrt{|x|^2|y|^2-(x\cdot y)^2}$$

Putting these together, we have

$$(a+b+c)(-a+b+c)(a-b+c)(a+b-c)=4((a^2b^2-(x\cdot y)^2)$$

What's nice is that this holds for vectors $x$ and $y$ in *any* dimension.  So now let $x=(2,1,0,0)$ and $y=(0,2,1,1)$, so that $x-y=(2,-1,-1,-1)$.  We have $a=\sqrt5$, $b=\sqrt6$, $c=\sqrt7$, and $x\cdot y=2$, and thus the OP's product of square roots simplifies to

$$4(5\cdot6-2^2) = 104$$

If you want to know why we went into the fourth dimension for the vectors $x$ and $y$, it's because $7$, like all positive integers, can be written as the sum of four squares, but not as the sum of three.  Another possibility, which makes it clear one can handle arbitrary $a$, $b$, and $c$ (as long as the triangle inequality is satisfied, at least) is to let $x=(1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0)$ and $y=(0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1)$, so that $x-y=(1,1,1,0,0,-1,-1,-1,-1)$. (**Edit**:  Actually, what I just said only works when the triangle inequality holds and $a+b+c$ is *even*.)

Comment: Sorry , but I don't understand why P has no terms with odd degree . Can you please explain it ?

Comment: @AGoogler, $P(a,b,c)=(P(a,b,c)+P(-a,b,c))/2$ rules out the possibility for $P$ to have any terms with $a$ of odd degree, and similarly for $b$ and $c$.

Answer (score 5):

Given that your original numbers are square roots and your expanded equation involves only even powers of your original numbers, you could say:

$$A=a^2=5, B=b^2=6, C=c^2=7$$

and simplify your equation to:

$$2(AB+AC+BC) - (A^2+B^2+C^2) = 2(30+35+42) - (25+36+49) = 214-110 = 104$$

Comment: What a great post for math!  Many different ways to solve the same problem....everyone gets a plus 1!!!!